# The best way of creating a unit test case for Snowflake database operations. Mock or real?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-unittest

I am actually new to writing unit test case and I have created one Mock unit test case like below which works fine.

```py
    class SnowflakeDbTest(TestCase):
    
        @patch('services.SnowflakeAPI.snowflake.connector')  # Decorator where  database object is configured...
        def test_get_database_connection(self, mock_connection):
            mock_connection.connect.return_value = "dbconnection"  # Setting up the mock value that would be returned after calling db get connection method...
            
            self.assertEqual("dbconnection",
                             SnowflakeApi.get_database_connection("user", "password", "account", "warehouse",
                                                                  database=None, schema=None))
```

Now, what I am trying to figure out is since I am able to test the mock one should I go ahead and implement the real one which will connect with the actual DB and check if the DB value passed by the user is present or not?

What is an ideal way of doing it? How can I go ahead with this? Or should I just keep it w.r.t mocks only.

Can anyone guide me with an example/links what would be the best way of doing it?